# Large files not linked correctly when I imported a private repo on Github

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I created a private repo named "**Proj**" to store my projects and used Git LFS to store the big files on Github. After that, I wanted to create another version of the repo. So I imported the first private repo "**Proj**" and named the new repo "**Proj-public**". The LFS for big files worked perfectly in my first repo "**Proj**", but when I turned to the second repo "**Proj-public**", I could only see the pointer files for those images shown like below, rather than the actual picture like what was shown in the first repo.

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:4e6dc2a5297236566862d27a470ec2f0baef49bb67d7099ae72e661cb0cc997d
size 54296
```

I chose to "include large files" when I imported the repo, but I suppose I've still lost the link to them. How can I fix the issue and let the large files shown as normal?
Many thanks!

Comment: Define 'big' in 'big files'. Also read [working with large files](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files) and [what is my disk quota](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota). and then give some more info

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Since it's unclear exactly how you created `Proj-public`, my guess is that the Git LFS configuration in the `.git` folder from the original `Proj` repo wasn't copied over to the new repo. There are some files there, namely `.git/info/lfs`, that Git LFS needs in order to function properly. So, what ended up happening, is that you copied all of the source files correctly, but not the Git LFS configuration, which is why you are just seeing the text pointers instead of the actual file contents like you would expect (e.g., images).

#### Going forward, do this

In the future, I recommend that if you want to create a copy of an existing repository, fork it. If you don't want the fork to have the parent linked in GitHub, you can do the following:

1. Clone the fork locally.
2. Rename it.
3. Delete the fork in GitHub.
4. Create a completely empty project in GitHub with the desired name for the fork.
5. Push the local fork to GitHub, which is technically no longer a fork in GitHub's eyes.

However, you should only do this with your own repositories and not with anyone else's code. You could get into some serious litigation trouble if you do this to a popular codebase while ignoring the LICENSE terms (if it has one).

So, let's proceed to your problem.

### Overview

I'm ripping much of this answer off from the Git LFS documentation. Take in case the [following](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/server-discovery.md):

> Git LFS will attempt to use your Git remote to determine the LFS server. You can also configure a custom LFS server if your Git remote doesn't support one, or you just want to use a separate one.  Look for the `Endpoint` properties in `git lfs env` to see your current LFS servers.

> By default, Git LFS will append `.git/info/lfs` to the end of a Git remote url to build the LFS server URL it will use. If Git LFS can't guess your LFS server, or you aren't using the `git-lfs-authenticate` command, you can specify the LFS server using Git config.

#### Set the LFS server

Set `lfs.url` to set the LFS server, regardless of Git remote:

```sh
$ git config lfs.url https://lfs-server.com/foo/bar
```

You can set `remote.{name}.lfsurl` to set the LFS server for that specific remote only:

```sh
$ git config remote.dev.lfsurl http://lfs-server.dev/foo/bar
$ git lfs env
```

#### Use .lfsconfig

Git LFS will also read these settings from a `.lfsconfig` file in the root of your repository. This lets you commit it to the repository so that all users can use it, or to keep the Git LFS configuration as a source of truth in your Git repository.

```sh
$ git config --file=.lfsconfig lfs.url https://lfs-server.com/foo/bar
```

#### Links

Git LFS documentation:

- [Client specification](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md)
- [Server specification (API)](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/master/docs/api)
- [Git LFS server discovery](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/server-discovery.md)